# deploy a pipeline with tensorflow in DSX

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, data-science-experience

I have a model built using python and tensorflow. 
The model is trained and works well. I don't understand how I can deploy it? I mean how can I call this model in order to obtain a score on actual data?
I cannot use Watson ML deploy because of TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

DSX supports training TensorFlow (without GPUs).  I hear DSX will support training TensorFlow with GPUs and then deploying into Watch Machine Learning (WML) in early 2018.

For other models that you've built in DSX using SparkML, ScikitLearn, XGBoost and SPSS, go here for details on how deploy using WML:

[Scala Jupyter Notebook end-to-end tutorial-Train and deploy a SparkML model](https://datascience.ibm.com/exchange/public/entry/view/d80de77f784fed7915c1435351309e93)

[Python Jupyter Notebook end-to-end tutorial-Train and deploy a SparkML model](https://datascience.ibm.com/exchange/public/entry/view/d80de77f784fed7915c14353512ef14d)

[Python Jupyter Notebook: Recognition of hand-written digits--Train and deploy Scikit Learn model](https://datascience.ibm.com/exchange/public/entry/view/acba02c8efecc5218b1d65ba9b8a5bbb)